# Symfony form nested fields

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have two fields, country and state, when I choose a country must reload the select box of cities.

[image]

As in this picture, countries are represented by buttons radio, when I choose a country the select must be under to that button radio to choose a state.

[image]

How I can implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using form type event listener predefined in Symfony stack, check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)